# How to create a List/Table of Summaries (with a summary per chapter)?

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to create a category at the beginning of every chapter, right after `\chapter{..}` summarizing it for the purpose of a list, it would be similar to Figure or Table (I would call it "Summary" or "Abstract") so I can build a "List/Table of Summaries" or abstracts. How can I do this?

using
\documentclass{book}
at the end have

\listoffigures
\listoftables

Would like to produce an equivalent list of abstracts.

I added

```
 \floatstyle{boxed}
```

\newfloat{summary}{tbp}{ext}

```
  \restylefloat*{summary}

    \floatname{summary}{Summary for Chapter }
```

but the problem is making the list.

Comment: `Figure` and `table` are floating environments, do you need your *abstracts* to float?

Comment: Yes, if possible. How do I set them?

Comment: If you really want them to float, have a look at the [newfloat](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat) package. Using a KOMA-script class, tocbasic does the trick. Can you edit your question to show a minimal example containing your documentclass?

Comment: So far half solved with the \newfloat but not for the table of summaries.

Comment: You could have added your tries to your question. As i see it now, the information does not go along with `newfloat`.

`\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
 fileext=abs,
 placement=H,
 listname={List of Chapterabstracts},
]{chapterabstract}`

Comment: Answerable in general (in more than one way) but unclear. The
implementation might be simple, usage as well, but the use of a
"List of abstracts" is odd: an abstract is normally text and given as one per document.